# Strange behaviour of default parameter value

Tags: ocaml

I just start learning OCaml. And I have a question, why this code outputs different results every time I call him?

```
let b () = Unix.time ();;
let a ?(c = b ()) () = c;;
a ();;
...
a ();;
```

I expected, that default value of **c** will be compute once.

Comment: Note that you can always obtain the behavior that would have seemed natural to you by writing `let current_time = b();; let a ?(c = current_time) () = c;;` instead of `let a ?(c = b ()) () = c;;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optional parameters are described in [Section 6.7](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) of the OCaml manual. Here's what it says:

> A function of the form

```
 fun ? lab :(  pattern =  expr0 ) ->  expr
```

> is equivalent to

```
fun ? lab : ident ->
    let pattern = match ident with
   | Some ident -> ident
   | None -> expr0
in
expr
```

> where ident is a fresh variable, except that it is unspecified when expr0 is evaluated.

This shows `expr0` being evaluated at each call, if the optional parameter is not supplied. I.e., `expr0` is inside the lambda, not outside.